# Разбивка большого файла xls на несколько меньших с помощью phpexel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Разбиваю большой **xls** файл на несколько мелких с помощью setReadFilter и $chunkFilter. Каждый кусок сохраняю в другой xls файл. Но получается что каждый следующий сохраненный файл содержит пустые ячейки.

Например было 5 строк  в файле, мне нужно разделить этот файл на 2 файла по 3 строки. 
В первом сохраненном файле будут первые 3 строки большого файла, а во втором - первые 3 строки будут пустые, а потом оставшиеся 2 строки.

Вот вопрос как избавится от этих пустых строк?

Вот сам код:

```
$file_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';
require_once $file_path . '../../PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
class chunkReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter 
{
private $_startRow = 0; 
private $_endRow = 0; 
/**  Set the list of rows that we want to read  */ 
public function setRows($startRow, $chunkSize) { 
    $this->_startRow    = $startRow; 
    $this->_endRow      = $startRow + $chunkSize; 
} 
public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') { 
    //  Only read the heading row, and the rows that are configured in 
$this->_startRow and $this->_endRow 
    if (($row >= $this->_startRow && $row < $this->_endRow)) { 
        return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
} 
}


$file_name = 'test1';
$file =  $file_path."../../vigruzka_aptek/".$file_name.".xls";

/*  some vars   */
$chunkSize = 3;     //размер считываемых строк за раз
$startRow = 1;          
$exit = false;          //флаг выхода
$empty_value = 0;       //счетчик пустых знаений
/*  some vars   */
if (!file_exists($file)) {
exit();
}

$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5($file);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$chunkFilter = new chunkReadFilter(); 
$objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter); 
//внешний цикл, пока файл не кончится
$j = 1;
while ( !$exit ) 
{
$chunkFilter->setRows($startRow,$chunkSize);    //устанавливаем знаечние фильтра
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);     //открываем файл
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);       //устанавливаем индекс активной страницы
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(); //делаем активной нужную страницу
for ($i = $startRow; $i < $startRow + $chunkSize; $i++)     //внутренний цикл по строкам
    {
    $value = trim(htmlspecialchars($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $i)->getValue()));       //получаем первое знаение в строке
    if ( empty($value) )        //проверяем значение на пустоту
        $empty_value++;         
    if ($empty_value == 3)      //после трех пустых значений, завершаем обработку файла, думая, что это конец
    {   
        $exit = true;   
        continue;       
    }   

}
//сохраняем файл
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save($file_path."../export/".$file_name.'-'.$j.".xls");

$objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();               //чистим 
unset($objPHPExcel);                        //память
$startRow += $chunkSize;                    //переходим на следующий шаг цикла, увеличивая строку, с которой будем читать файл
$j++;
}
```